# Proving a cone in $\mathbb R^n$ has at most $n$ affinely independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am aware that affine independence in $\mathbb R^n$ is equivalent to linear independence in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, which imply that the maximum number of affinely independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ is $n+1$. But I do not understand why this imply that for any cone in $\mathbb R^n$, the maximum number is $n$?

My instructor said something along the lines of, if you have started out with a plane in $\mathbb R^n$, you can "bump" it up one dimension by forming a cone so that it is still true that it has at most $n+1$ dimension. But this explanation makes very little sense to me, I do not see how one can formalize this explanation.

Can someone shine some light on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe I don't know what you mean by "cone", but the three points $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(1,2)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ are affinely independent, and they're contained in the positive quadrant which (to me) is a cone. For that matter, any two distinct positive real numbers are affinely independent in $\Bbb R^1$ and are contained in the cone $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yeah I think I am phrasing my question incorrectly. Basically, my professor was telling us if we have a cone generated by m points in R^n, then for any x in the cone, we can find at most n many affinely independent points in the generating set s.t. the cone generated by this subset will contain this point. I think a reasonable definition of a cone generated by points is the set of all linear combinations of the points where the coefficients are positive. Somehow we were supposed to be able to use the fact that in $R^n$ there are at most $R^{n+1}$ affinely independent vectors.

Comment: I think if I am able to prove that any hyper plane in $R^n$ contains at most n affinely independent points we can use this result to "cut" the cone through any given point, problem is I don't even see how to prove that it is true.

Comment: You should add your goal "any hyperplane in $\Bbb R^n$ contains at most $n$ affinely independent points" to your post. Do you know the formal definition of "affinely independent"? What happens when you apply it to $n+1$ points in a hyperplane in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Ah I see, one can easily translate "n+1 points {x1....x_n+1}" being affinely independent" on the hyperplane in R^n to {x1-v, x2-v....} being affinely independent, since if the later was dependent we can use the fact that the coefficients sum to 0 to "bum" the vectors in the subspace hyperplane to the original hyperplane "by adding a single vector".